# Reference request regarding Mackey topology

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, topological-vector-spaces

I would like to ask for some request on the relationship between Mackey topology and the weak topology. Recently, I have read quite some statements where a property in weak topology (such as compactness) implies that in Mackey topology. The basic connection I have now is that the topology is identitical if we are talking about an equicontinuous subset. However, I have a feeling that there must be something more. The reference I got is schaefer, *Topological Vector Space* and Bourbaki, *Topological Vector Space*. However, both of the books are quite brief on this matter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The basic reference is [Topological Vector Space](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387987262), the second is [Bourbaki's classic](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540645634). Other books on Topological Spaces also can be mentioned. However, I want to mention another direction which might interest you.

The Banach Lattice Theory (or more general form), makes it very easy to find Mackey topology. The most important space $L$-space and $M$-space can be identify with $L_1$ and $C(X)$, therefore, it is extremely easy get from weak to Mackey thanks to [Banach–Alaoglu theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem)
, the basic reference for lattice theory is [enter link description here](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540542018). However, it doesn't reveal the full power. For the full power, see [this notorious hard-to-read book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387963073), from chatper 1 to chapter 10, as well as the appendix.